# how can one recognize inputs from multiple keys simultaneously in c (linux)

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, pthreads, simultaneous

I am trying to create ping pong in C using ncurses, and I have right now a huge setback because I can't figure out how I can allow two players to move the pads simultaneously. What I've tried is creating a seperate thread which would then use select to detect any buffered key presses and then put that into an array containing my controls. However, it only reads the first key and doesn't recognize the other.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define DELAY 30000

#define P1_UP 0
#define P1_DOWN 1
#define P2_UP 2
#define P2_DOWN 3

struct player {
    int x;
    int y;
    int score;
};

void *_thread_func(void *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct player p[2];
  int x, y, max_y, max_x;
  int *keys;
  pthread_t _thread;

  keys = calloc(4, sizeof(int));

  if(pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, _thread_func, &keys) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(FALSE);

  getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);

  p[0].score = p[1].score = 0;
  p[0].y = p[1].y = max_y/2-3; // length of pad is 6
  p[0].x = 0; // width of pad is 1
  p[1].x = max_x-1;
  while(1) {
    getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);

    clear();

    mvprintw(p[0].y  , p[0].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[0].y+1, p[0].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[0].y+2, p[0].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[0].y+3, p[0].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[0].y+4, p[0].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[0].y+5, p[0].x  , "|");

    mvprintw(p[1].y  , p[1].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[1].y+1, p[1].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[1].y+2, p[1].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[1].y+3, p[1].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[1].y+4, p[1].x  , "|");
    mvprintw(p[1].y+5, p[1].x  , "|");

    refresh();
    usleep(DELAY);

    if(keys[P2_UP]) {
      keys[P2_UP] = 0;
      if(--p[1].y < 0) p[1].y++; 
    }

    if(keys[P2_DOWN]) {
      keys[P2_DOWN] = 0;
      if(++p[1].y >= max_y-5) p[1].y--; 
    }

    if(keys[P1_UP]) {
      keys[P1_UP] = 0;
      if(--p[0].y < 0) p[0].y++; 
    }

    if(keys[P1_DOWN]) {
      keys[P1_DOWN] = 0;
      if(++p[0].y >= max_y-5) p[0].y--; 
    }
  }

  free(keys);

  endwin();
}


void *_thread_func(void *arg) {
  fd_set readfds;
  int    num_readable;
  int    num_bytes;
  struct timeval tv;
  int    **keys;
  char   buf[1];
  int    fd_stdin;

  keys = (int**) arg;
  fd_stdin = fileno(stdin);

  while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    fflush(stdout);
    num_readable = select(fd_stdin + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (num_readable == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "\nError in select : %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }
    if (num_readable > 0) {
      num_bytes = read(fd_stdin, buf, 1);
      if (num_bytes < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError on read : %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
      }

      switch(buf[0]) {
        case 105: /* i -> ascii 105*/
          (*keys)[P2_UP] = 1;
          break;
        case 107: /* k -> ascii 107*/
          (*keys)[P2_DOWN] = 1;
          break;
        case 119: /* w -> ascii 119*/
          (*keys)[P1_UP] = 1;
          break;
        case 115: /* s -> ascii 115*/
          (*keys)[P1_DOWN] = 1;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

How can I in C recognize more than one keys down at the same time? Any example on how this can be done would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Anyway, it's not supported by standard C, you have to use platform-specific functions to read the keyboard status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, you can change the keyboard mode using `ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, mode)` where `mode` is one of `K_RAW`, `K_XLATE`, `K_MEDIUMRAW` or `K_UNICODE`. If you set it to `K_RAW`, then you will receive raw scancodes; most keys send one scan code when pressed and another scancode when released.

In this mode, it's up to you to keep track of which keys are pressed and which ones are not pressed.

The precise scancodes sent by individual keys may vary a bit from keyboard to keyboard. You can use `showkeys -s` to experiment (but I recommend doing this from console mode, rather than through the X graphical interface).

You'll need special privileges to change the keyboard mode, by the way.

Also, make sure that you restore the keyboard mode to what it was before you changed it -- even if your program crashes. Otherwise, you may render your console unusable, and you'll be forced to reboot (or ssh into your machine from another machine on your network, if you've enabled `sshd` and have another machine on your network.)

See `man console_ioctl` for more information.

There will be similar features on other operating systems. Look around in the `ioctl` documentation.

Comment: Okay, that seems useful, would you be so kind to provide a small example in C :)

Comment: Well, here's the source for `showkey`: https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd/+/1.10/src/showkey.c It's a pretty small example. It doesn't actually track keys, but that's the easy part. (You could use a small vector of booleans, for example.) By the way, autorepeat is not affected by K_RAW, so if the key is pressed, you'll continue to get periodic keydown scancodes. That can be useful, if you don't actually want to keep track of key status.

Comment: Can I just compile it using the provided makefile in the source code or is there a way to directly compile it? #include "getfd.h" is obviously not going to work if I compile it individually :)

Comment: @Linus: You shouldn't need to compile it; if you have Linux, you'll almost certainly find `showkey` already present on your system. The point of the source code is to read it for an example of the system calls. Pay particular attention to the way the author ensures that the keyboard mode is restored on exit: that's the reason for all those sigactions.

Comment: Nevermind, I just ran the example found in /usr/bin/showkey

Answer (score 2):

The example and approach given won't work for more than one reason:

1. the curses library won't be thread-safe
2. there's only one input device opened (making a select-call pointless).

A curses program could be opened on multiple devices using [newterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html), and use timeouts to poll for input from those devices.  The ditto.c program in [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) would be useful reading for this.

Comment: it wasn't meant to be thread-safe, it was just me folling around with ideas to create a program accepting multiple inputs in C. Thanks for the links by the way.